# How to check whether my view page is not on top position using JavaScript events?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How can I detect if a web page is not on top using a wheel event or scrollbar move?

My code is partly working. The header is on top, the `startPosition` get a value which is bigger than 0 only after the second wheel scrolling, but it should be after the first wheel scrolling.
Also, the wheel event is not firing when I scrolling the page using the scroll bar.

So how can I detect if my page is not on top?

For example:

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', (event)=>{
   var target = document.querySelector('.main-header'); //Header which on top
   var targetPosition = target.getBoundingClientRect().top;
   var startPosition = window.pageYOffset;
   var distance = targetPosition - startPosition;
   console.log(event);
   if(startPosition>0){
      upScrl.style.display = 'block';
   }
   else{
      upScrl.style.display = 'none';
   }  
})
```

Comment: Did you try `onscroll` event? https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onscroll2

Answer (score 0):

Working, thanks to @Stefan Wang

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

myFunction = () => {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    upScrl.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    upScrl.style.display = 'none';
  }
```

}